# How to iterate through two pandas columns and create a new column

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I am trying to create a new column by concatenating two columns with certain conditions.

```
master['work_action'] = np.nan
for a,b in zip(master['repair_location'],master['work_service']):
    if a == 'Field':
        master['work_action'].append(a + " " + b)
    elif a == 'Depot':
        master['work_action'].append(a + " " + b)
    else:
        master['work_action'].append(a)

TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'str'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid
```

The problem is with `master['work_action'].append(a + " " + b)`

If I change my code to this:

```
test = []
for a,b in zip(master['repair_location'],master['work_service']):
    if a == 'Field':
        test.append(a + " " + b)
    elif a == 'Depot':
        test.append(a + " " + b)
    else:
        test.append(a)
```

I get exactly what I want in a list. But I want it in a pandas column. How do I create a new pandas column with the conditions above?

Comment: `df['work_action'] = [f'{a} {b}' if a in {'Field', 'Depot'} else a for a, b in zip(df['repair_locaiton'], df['work_service])]`

Comment: I like your `zip` approach.  I'd add some efficiency by wrapping it in a list comprehension.

Comment: Thanks! There are some typos in your solution but it worked! `master['work_action'] = [f'{a} {b}' if a in {'Field', 'Depot'} else a for a, b in zip(master['repair_location'], master['work_service'])]` Please add it to the answer and I'll give you credit

Comment: did you try using `.loc` methods or `np.where`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If performance is important, I would use `numpy`'s `select`:

```
master = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'repair_location': ['Field', 'Depot', 'Other'],
        'work_service':[1, 2, 3]
    }
)

master['work_action'] = np.select(
    condlist= [
        master['repair_location'] == 'Field',
        master['repair_location'] == 'Depot'
    ],
    choicelist= [
        master['repair_location'] + ' ' + master['work_service'].astype(str),
        master['repair_location'] + ' ' + master['work_service'].astype(str)
    ],
    default= master['repair_location']
)
```

Which results in:

```
  repair_location  work_service work_action
0           Field             1     Field 1
1           Depot             2     Depot 2
2           Other             3       Other
```

Answer (score -1):

Append method is for insert values at the end. You are trying to concatenate two strings values. Use `apply` method:

```
def fun(a,b):
    if a == 'Field':
        return a + " " + b
    elif a == 'Depot':
        return a + " " + b
    else:
       return a

master['work_action'] = master.apply(lambda x: fun(x['repair_location'], x['work_service']), axis=1)
```

Comment: `apply` is a loop.  There is nothing "vectorized" about it.  It is a convenience method and should **NOT** be construed as some optimized version of a `for` loop.

Comment: It looks like there's a missing `)` I added it in and got an error: `KeyError: ('repair_location', 'occurred at index address')`